# How to install insulation in a small space behind an existing shower?

Tags: bathroom, walls, insulation, exterior

I have a 3" wide area the height of the bathroom wall behind at the corner of an existing shower on the external wall without insulation. The space runs the full 8' height I can only reach the top 8" or so that is above the shower wall. Is it a problem that this space is not insulated? Any recommendations how to fill the space to the floor with insulation and provide a vapor barrier?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the shower and build the wall right
- Or forget the vapor barrier and blow in cellulose.

If you really want a probable horror show, spray foam it, but I would not recommend that if you don't want a horror show - it will probably overexpand and warp or crack the shower enclosure.

If you don't insulate it that will be an uncomfortable shower (I've lived with that junk in places I didn't build. Would not recommend.)

Comment: It appears that the shower is installed with some drywall screws, so it shouldn't be terribly difficult to remove, so long as there's access to the drain from below.